# How to create MapElement3D from a 3mf file?

Tags: c#, uwp, 3d

I am trying to create a UWP MapElement3D object from a 3mf file inside the Assets folder of my Visual Studio Project. However, I keep getting this error:

> Failed to create MapModel3D from 3MF stream.

This is where my code crashes:

```
RandomAccessStreamReference reference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Crane.3mf"));
var myModel = await MapModel3D.CreateFrom3MFAsync(reference, MapModel3DShadingOption.Smooth);
```

My goal is to render that 3D model into a MapControl component.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that `MapModel3D` cannot read 3mf files correctly, you can try the following:

1. right-click your `Assets/Crane.3mf` file, choose the `Properties`
2. Set **Build Action** to `Content`.

This will include the 3mf file in the package and `MapModel3D` will be able to access it correctly.

Best regards.